# draw.io pressing enter moves entire page

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Pressing enter on draw.io (new line in text) moves the entire page instead of just expanding the text document.

Look at the difference between text and heading. Notice how text moves the entire page whereas heading is the proper way.

[image]

What is the problem here? How to make text behave like heading?

Comment: What domain are you loading in from? What is the browser and version? Any browser extensions? What operating system? What is the version in the help menu?

Comment: I've tried chrome and edge. Latest version, same result. I've tried on a guest window in chrome with no extension. Same result. Windows 10 19044.1586

Answer (score 1):

We managed to reproduce the issue in Chrome incognito but this is not an easy fix. Could you test this in FF? It should behave correctly in Firefox.

Comment: Great. Seems to work normally on firefox! Although for Chrome, regular and incognito both fail for me. I'll just use firefox I guess

Comment: Any idea what causes this? Or what the fix is?